# Is this function $f(x) smooth despite it not being continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Define the function $f(x)$ as follows:
$$ \begin{cases} f(x)=1 &\text{if } x>0 \\ f(x)=0 &\text{if } x=0 \\ f(x)=-1 &\text{if } x<0\end{cases}
$$
Now, $f(x)$ is not continuos at $x=0$ because $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ fails to exist. However, it appears that $f$ is differentiable everywhere, Since $f'(x)=0$ onall of $\mathbb{R}$. It would also appear that $f$ is smooth, or of class $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

However, I thought that if a function was differentiable at a point, then it was also continuous there?

Comment: why do you think $f'(0)$ exists?

Comment: $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h-0}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1}{|h|}=+\infty$

Comment: differentiability $\implies$ continuity.

Comment: Draw the graph, you can clearly see there are problems at $0$

Answer (score 6):

No, f' is **not** 0 for all x.  The derivative of your function at x= 0 is given by $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)- f(0)}{h}$.  To do that limit, look at the limits "from below" and "from above".  For x< 0, f(x)= -1 so we have $\lim_{h\to 0^-} \frac{-1- 0}{h}$ **does not exist**.  Similarly, for x> 0 f(x)= 1 so we have $\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{1- 0}{h}$ **does not exist**. The derivative of f is equal to 0 for all x **except** x= 0 where the derivative does not exist.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.